# Typeahead issue - Ajax only returning Json data once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, typeahead

I've been pulling my hair out for a few hours with Twitter's Typeahead plugin.

Basically, we're pulling the data from a web service (an Asmx webservice) with a response format of .JSON.

Once we get it via BloodHound, we then convert it into a string, strip out some additional characters before re-converting it into Json and then passing it to Typeahead.

```
 var engine= new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function (d) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace("value")
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch : {
            ttl : 1000,
            url : '/webservice.asmx'
        },
        remote: {
            ttl : 1000,
            url: '/webservice.asmx',
            ajax: {
                beforeSend: function (jqXhr, settings) {
                    jqXhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
                    settings.data = '{"query":"' + $('#inputText').val() + '"}';
                    alert(settings.data);
                },
                type: "POST",
                context: this
            },
            filter: function (response) {
                //return response;
                if (response.hasOwnProperty('d')) {

                    var returned = String(response.d);
                    returned = returned.slice(14,-1);

    var parsedJSON =     jQuery.parseJSON(returned);
                    return  parsedJSON ;
                }
                else {
                    return response;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    engine.initialize();

    $('#inputText').typeahead(null, {
        source: engine.ttAdapter()
    });
```

When typing into the input field, the code fetches the data based on the query via Ajax ONCE and ONCE ONLY, however it passes it through the filter multiple times when the user types more characters into the input box. I believe this is the problem. Because we have to use a type of POST due to the method of using a Asmx webservice, Ajax doesn't seem to be able to make more than one request, no matter how many characters we type into the input box.

As I say, this has been driving us mad for a few days now so any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog helped solve the answer - http://www.weezey.com/2014/03/bringing-it-all-together/

Looked like we overcomplicated things a bit. We still had to strip out and reconvert the Json our webserver was spitting back in the Ajax section, but we got it working.